# How to use constant values for TypeScript 'Type Aliases' types?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am new in TypeScript.

On an Angular Project, I am preparing a SnackBar Service in order to notify user.

I have some Java background.

I have two question.

In TypeScript while defining a class I can not use "const" keyword. And my service going to be a singleton so if it changes the my value accidently in somewhere my whole application gonna break. Because of that I tried private field. But I think it is not enough.

1) TypeScript can provide us someting like const for a class field?

In my service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SnackService {

  private DURATION = 1800;

  private HORIZANTAL_POSITION = 'end';

  constructor(private sncackBar: MatSnackBar) {

  }

  successful(message: string) {
    this.sncackBar.open(message, null, {
      duration: this.DURATION,
      horizontalPosition: this.HORIZANTAL_POSITION,
      panelClass: 'success-snackBar'
    });
  }

  error(message: string) {
    this.sncackBar.open(message, null, {
      duration: this.DURATION,
      horizontalPosition: this.HORIZANTAL_POSITION,
      panelClass: 'error-snackBar'
    });
  }
}
```

2) Because of 'Type Aliases' my code is not compiling. How could I use const values for 'Type Aliases'?

Above class is not compiling and message is :

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ duration: number; horizontalPosition: string; panelClass: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MatSnackBarConfig<any>'.
  Types of property 'horizontalPosition' are incompatible.
```

But in 'MatSnackBarConfig', 'MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition ' already a string.

```
export declare type MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'start' | 'center' | 'end' | 'left' | 'right';
```

Comment: you could simply check what `MatSnackBarConfig<any>` actually is and the second problem should be solved after that

Comment: you would need to import MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition and assign this type to you private HORIZONTAL_POSITION value

Comment: also you have a typo in this.sncackBar

Comment: a singleton can be kept in a static class field, later you can make sure that there is no single instance already instantiated in the constructor

Comment: if you capitalize your variable names because you want them to be constants you could do with `readonly` modifier

Comment: Thanks Daniel, making the type of field "MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition" solved the compiling problem and I didn't know the 'readonly' keyword thanks.
And extra thanks for typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with string literal types not type aliases. A string literal type is a subtype of `string` so you can assign the type `'end'`  to a string but not the other way around.

You can make the compiler infer a string literal type for a field if it is readonly

```
private readonly HORIZANTAL_POSITION = 'end';
```

If the field is not readonly you can manually specify the type

```
private HORIZANTAL_POSITION : MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'end';
```